# php and mysql unique serial

Tags: php, mysql

could be a simple question but i just have to know this.

suppose i have a column in my table that i need to store **unique number** as **serial**..structure as below

```
+-------------------------------------+
|id         |    year        | serial |
+-------------------------------------+
|1000       |   2013         |        |
+-------------------------------------+
|1001       |   2013         |        |
+-------------------------------------+
```

the **id(is not auto increment)** and **year are passed from a web form**.

during **record creation**,i want **serial column** to be the result of **(id+year+exact creation time of record**).

**question 1:**
is it posibble to create it as such

**question2:**
suppose id and year are gotten from a web form and i **upload csv file with 1000 records(probably in transaction)**,will the serial still be unique

Comment: So the problem is the unique id itself? You're not sure if it will be unique? Does it have to be in a certain format or just unique and that's it?

Comment: _Question 1_ - Yes this should be possible, at least if you do it in php (it's also most likely do able in the mysql end.) _Question 2_ That will depend on the data from your csv files, if you have duplicate data in the csv file then no, it won't be unique. - You might want to consider how you generate the ID's and such to ensure that you don't get duplicate values. Without telling us how you generate the data it's hard to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: @Andrew yes am not sure they will be unique if i do as above  but all i need is for them to be unique

Comment: @Epodax my csv data will have unique id

Comment: You could use something like this `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))` for the unique_id, but it doesn't have any special meaning attached to it, it is however unqiue enough. But it would be a whole lot easier to set an `id` column with autoincrement.

Comment: I recommend to add uniqid() to each serial or use mysql function UUID_SHORT()

Comment: @Andrew i already have a an autoincrement id. the serial column will also be used as index

Comment: Well in that case the serial is pointless. The AI column is the thing you need.

Answer (score 0):

**yes you can use this code:**

Step 1. Fetch the data from the database last id

```
$result = $conn -> query("SELECT ag_id FROM ag_reg ORDER BY ag_id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Step2. Now increment fetch and with add+1 the last id and save it into the database

```
    $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
    $id_value = $row['ag_id'];
    $new_id_value = $id_value + 1;
```

Comment: Just tell him to use AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Save the last id and he can, increment From the front side !!